# How to vertically center Text in TouchableOpacity?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I am trying to vertically center Text in a TouchableOpacity but it is hard to get it done for me.

My App.tsx:

```
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View } from "react-native";

import { CustomButton } from "./src/components/CustomButton";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <CustomButton title="Button" />
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});
```

And my CustomButton.tsx:

```
import React from "react";
import {
  TouchableOpacity,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
} from "react-native";

interface CustomButtonProps {
  title: string;
}

export const CustomButton = ({ title }: CustomButtonProps): JSX.Element => {
  return (
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonTitle}>{title}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  button: {
    borderRadius: 4,
    width: 240,
    height: 100,
    backgroundColor: "#FFF",
    marginBottom: 12,
  },
  buttonTitle: {
    alignSelf: "center",
    fontSize: 24,
    color: "#fff",
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
});
```

Currently I set `alignSelf` in buttonTitle as 'center' but I have also tried:

- textAlign: 'center' in buttonTitle,
- alignItems: 'center' in button,
- alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' in button

And many other ways I could find on Google but none of them worked. It only centers the Text horizontally. Can anyone help me with **vertically** centering Text of this TouchableOpacity component?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It has to be `display: flex` to handle your `justify-content` attribute. You are looking for `display: "flex",alignItems: "center"` or `display: "flex", flexFlow: "column". justifyContent: "center"`. This question is about CSS, not React and not even about _Text in TouchableOpacity_. Learn more about [flex at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex).

Comment: None of your suggestions works and flexFlow is not even valid in React Native. And do you see CSS is in the tags? What do you mean this question is not even about Text or TouchableOpacity when they are literally what I am trying to use? :)

Comment: And what I have done is literally following the example that the React Native documentation has: https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchableopacity seems things are being centered there with the same attributes I tried to use but not working on mine.

Comment: Set justifyContet: 'center', alignItems: 'center' in button style. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved:

React Native's default direction is `column` which is different than the web.

Thus, what I needed is to add `justifyContent: "center"` within the `button` styles, so the code looks like:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  button: {
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    borderRadius: 4,
    width: 240,
    height: 100,
    backgroundColor: "#FFF",
    marginBottom: 12,
  },
  buttonTitle: {
    fontSize: 24,
    color: "#fff",
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
});
```

Hope it helps those who encounter the same problem!

Answer (score 2):

Have a try by using `textAlign: 'center'` in the style of the text component.

also, you can refer to the official docs from here.

[React native Text Compoent](https://reactnative.dev/docs/text)

Comment: I already tried that (written in the post) and it does not work.. what am I possibly missing?